# ¿cómo importar un archivo .py que esta en una carpeta diferente, en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Soy muy nuevo en la programación en Python. He creado un proyecto de escritorio el cual me sirve para aprender aspectos importantes del lenguaje. Utilizo las librerias PyQT5 y PySide2 para el diseño interfaz apoyandome tambien en Qt Designer. En este proyecto, he creado un archivo main.py, desde el cual inicio mi aplicación, llamó allí algunas funciones que pertenecen a otros modulos, abro y cierro ventanas, etc. En ese archivo main.py yo importo el archivo archivo2.py que se encuentra ubicado en la carpeta subcarpeta1. Lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
#ventana principal 
from carpeta1.subcarpeta1.archivo2 import *
```

esto funciona perfectamente. El problema surgió cuando intenté importar el archivo archivo2.py ubicado en la carpeta subcarpeta2, dentro del archivo archivo2.py ubicado en la carpeta subcarpeta1. Lo hice de esta manera:

```
 #archivo archivo2.py ubicado en la carpeta subcarpeta1
 import sys
 sys.path.append("..")
 from subcarpeta2.archivo2 import *
```

En la consola me arroja el siguiente error (y el programa no inicia):

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "subcarpeta2"
```

Alguien podria ayudarme a solucionar este error?

Esta es una imagen de la estructura del proyecto:

[image: Estructura del proyecto desktop python]

Comment: No se si esta sea la causa de tu error, pero donde haces `sys.path.append("..")`, cambia el path por "../" a ver que pasa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El segundo import no te funciona porque no estás teniendo en cuenta desde donde estás ejecutando el programa. Como se puede observar, el programa se ejecuta dentro des de el `main.py`, que está al nivel de carpeta1. Por tanto, todos tus imports deben ser referenciados desde ese nivel. Es decir, en tu caso, aunque te encuentres dentro del archivo2 de la subcarpeta1, tienes que hacer referencia a carpeta 1 para poder acceder a subcarpeta2:

```
from carpeta1.subcarpeta2.archivo2.py import *
```

Otra forma de hacer el import es mediante imports relativos. Esta forma no funciona igual que la anterior. Como puedes observar, subcarpeta1 y subcarpeta2 están a la misma altura en el grafo de directorios (son hermanos), por tanto puedes acceder a ellas de la siguiente manera:

```
from ..subcarpeta2.archivo2.py import *
```

Donde `..` hace referencia a el directorio padre del directorio del archivo actual (como en los sistemas UNIX), es decir, el directorio carpeta1. Esta forma no tiene en cuenta desde donde se ejecuta el programa principal, sino donde está ubicado el archivo desde donde se hace el import.

Comment: Gracias, ahora funciona!.

Comment: Perfecto se me ha olvidado comentarte que carpeta1 tendría que tener también __init__.py para hacer el import relativo.