# Error de importación de un módulo de Python en un directorio superior

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, unittest

Estoy practicando un poco de Python. Tengo el archivo test_car.py donde intento importar el módulo capulet_engine que está en el directorio Engine.

Pero no me deja importarlo. Ya intenté con "from Engine import capulet", "from .Engine.capulet_engine import capulet", "from ..Engine.capulet_engine import capulet", etc., pero nada parece funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, antes de crear una publicación es importante revisar las existentes, esta pregunta ha sido resuelta multiples veces. Un ejemplo de una pregunta similar: [¿cómo importar un archivo .py que esta en una carpeta diferente, en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429453/c%c3%b3mo-importar-un-archivo-py-que-esta-en-una-carpeta-diferente-en-python)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato también quería probar hacer una pregunta ya que nunca lo había hecho. De igual forma, la solución la encontré en otro foro y es diferente a la que planteas. De cualquier manera, gracias!

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Al código ponlo siempre como texto, con formato. A la estructura de las carpetas puedes mostrarla como texto también. Siempre debes preguntar en [es.so] _como último recurso_. Y si ya encontraste respuesta, ¡redáctala y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer)! Aquí se pregunta no solo para buscar ayudar para sí mismo, sino también para ayudar con las respuestas a otras personas que lleguen a tener un problema similar.