# Por que me sale un error cuando importo un archivo de Python que se encuentra en otra carpeta?

Tags: python

estoy empezado en Python. Cuanto importo un archivo de Python que se encuentra en una carpeta me sale el error !ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'!, como puedo importar mi archivo de una cárpete a otra, Python no me permite trabajar con dos carpetas?

Adjunto una imagen para que me puede ayudar, ya llevo semanas con esto y no logro importar mi archivo de otra carpeta.

Gracias antemano por la ayuda.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, antes de crear una publicación es importante revisar las existentes, esta pregunta ha sido resuelta multiples veces. Un ejemplo de una pregunta similar: [¿cómo importar un archivo .py que esta en una carpeta diferente, en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429453/c%c3%b3mo-importar-un-archivo-py-que-esta-en-una-carpeta-diferente-en-python)

Comment: Estas importando mal. Debería ser:  from .config import db.message. Agregar el punto (.) antes del modulo que deseas importar toma la ruta absoluta de este.